# ¿Cómo hacer que el botón "Editar" muestre el dato requerido?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

```
<?php

include "../../assets/php/conexion_bd.php";

    //Mostrar Datos
    if(empty($_GET['id'])) {

        header("location: ../../materias.php");

    }

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $query_materias = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT id_categoria, nombre FROM materias_biblioteca");

    $result_materias = mysqli_num_rows($query_materias);

    if($result_materias == 0) {

        header('location: ../../materias.php');

    }else{

        $option = '';

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query_materias)) {

            # code...
            $id = $data['id_categoria'];
            $nombre = $data['nombre'];

        }

    }

?>
```

Tengo este código de base de datos, lo que hace el código es tomar el dato según donde yo hice click en la etiqueta "a", el siguiente código es del botón editar

```
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <a href="assets/php/edicion_archivos.php?id=<?php echo $data["id_categoria"]; 
                    ?>"
                    style="text-decoration: none; color: #fff;">
                        <span  class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" 
                        data-target="#modalActualizarMateria">
                            <span class="fas fa-edit"></span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </td>
```

Hago click en ese botón y se supone que me lo debería mostrar en el siguiente código que va junto con el primer código de php que mostré

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/img/logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/style-agregar-u.css">
    <title>Actualizar Usuarios - MiLFL</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="form-container">
        <h2>Actualizar usuario</h2>

        <form action="assets/php/actualizar_usuario_bd.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
            <label for="">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre Completo" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre ?>">
            </select>
            <button>Actualizar</button>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

El error es que haga click donde haga click, siempre aparece el último dato agregado a la DB. La etiqueta "A" redirecciona junto con el ID que la persona seleccionó pero, la función no es realizada
[image: Esta es la sección biblioteca, el botón amarillo es el de editar y me lleva a otra página para poder editar el nombre de la materia]

[image: Esta es la sección donde se actualiza, debería aparecer el nombre de la materia, pero, solamente figura el último dato añadido a la DB]

Comment: Debes generar el botón editar dentro del `while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query_materias)) {` para que te coga un id distinto cada vez. Si lo haces fuera, tal como lo tienes, la variable contiene el último valor del while solamente, porque en cada ciclo la has ido sobreescribiendo, y por eso se te repite en todas partes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro, es porque estás iterando el ciclo y retornando el último registro al `href`.

Para solucionarlo, tienes dos opciones:

- Retornar el array `$data` e iterarlo en el `HTML`.
- Maquetar el `HTML` dentro del ciclo `while` y retornarlo ya listo.

Por ejemplo:

```
    $option = '';

    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query_materias)) {
        ...
        $option .= '<a href="assets/php/edicion_archivos.php?id='.$data["id_categoria"].';
        ...

    }
    echo $option;
```

Con cualquier opción obtendrás el resultado que buscas. Sólo adapta el ejemplo a tu código.